# World of Warships mobile to PC

Tags: world-of-warships

I play world of warships on my phone and I just got the game on steam and was wondering if I could transfer my save data and have all my ships on pc without having to work towards them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **World of Warships: Blitz** (mobile) and **World of Warships PC** are very similar, they are separate versions on separate systems, accounts and progress cannot be transferred between the two systems. Accounts for **World of Warships** on PC and **World of Warships: Blitz** (mobile) will not/cannot be unified for any players or any reasons.

All purchases for your WoWS: Blitz must be made **through the Google Play Games/App Store interface, which goes through the Google/Apple owned Play Store/App Store, respectively**. Only content that is purchased through these companies can be credited to those accounts, on that specific platform.

**World of Warships: Blitz** is also a separate title from the PC version of **World of Warships**, all progress, content and purchases on this platform is not shared and non-transferable.

Player’s data is stored differently on all four versions of the game and all in game content vary from platform to platform making it impossible to transfer the owned content in its current owned state.